# Single-Syllable Words, a Comprehensive List

Tags: vocabulario

I am learning Spanish as a fluent American English speaker. I thought it would help to memorize all single-syllable Spanish words so I can build a quick foundation and help to catch those words when people are speaking to me.

So far, I've not found any comprehensive list online, but I have found the evidence that other people are searching for it. So, maybe we can compile one here. I'd like to list all words (1-5 characters) with English definitions, and maybe pronunciation keys. I did find some help from Scrabble sites...

2-letter words: http://spanish.about.com/od/vocabularygamesandpuzzle/a/two-letter-words.htm

scroll to 4-letter & under: http://www.wordfind.com/word/espanol/

Thanks for the help!
Pedro

Comment: Good idea. But in my opinion as a learner of languages, the best "basics" start, other than common phrases, are the kids shows in a language. I suggest you to start from there, if you want to take the approach of "basic patterns first". Anyways, I posted an answer below. Hope you can find those words useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search brought me the link and words I will detail below, in case we lost the wiktionary site in the future.

https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ndice:Monosilabos

a
al
ar
as
ax
bah
bar
be
bel
bien
bis
bit
boj
bol
bon
brin
bus
buz
cal
can
car
ce
cha
che
ché
chin
chip
cho
cid
clan
clon
col
con
coz
cran
crin
crol
cron
cruz
cu
da
dad
dan
das
de
dé
del
di
dí
do
don
dos
e
el
él
en
erg
es
ex
fa
fan
fax
faz
fe
fez
fin
fiel
flan
flor
flux
folk
frez
fu
ga
gas
ge
gel
gen
gil
gin
gis
gol
gong
gran
gres
gris
gu
gui
gus
ha
han
has
haz
he
hez
hiel
hoz
i
ir
ka
krill
la
lar
las
le
les
lo
los
luz
lux
mal
mar
mas
más
me
mes
mi
mí
mil
mis
mol
mor
mu
mur
mus
na
ni
no
non
nos
ña
ño
ñor
ñu
o
oc
oh
os
ox
pe
pal
pan
par
paz
pez
pi
pin
pie
piel
plan
plus
pon
pop
por
pos
prez
pro
pus
que
qué
ras
re
red
res
rip
rol
ron
ros
rus
sal
sál
san
se
sé
sed
sel
sen
ser
si
sí
sic
sil
sin
so
sol
son
sor
sos
su
sud
sur
sus
tac
tal
tan
tas
taz
te
té
ten
test
tex
tez
ti
tic
ton
tos
tras
tren
tres
tris
tu
tú
tul
tun
u
ud
un
va
val
vals
van
vas
ve
vé
ven
ver
ves
vez
vi
vil
vis
vos
voz
watt
y
ya
yang
ye
yen
yin
yo
zig
zag
zas
zar
zen

Comment: And several of these can be made plural this making it bigger.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Herman's answer there is this other link however I completely agree with Herman This is useless. As a native speaker I don't even know the meaning of some of those words and some may even have several meanings depending on the context, so I think memorizing these lists would be a waste of time...but suit yourself :-)

[www.wikilengua.org](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Monos%C3%ADlabos_ortogr%C3%A1ficos)

guion
pie
pio
piais
pieis
rio
riais
ruan
Ruan
Sion
Saiz
Sainz
Lion
ruo
ruais
rue
rueis
ruin
guio
guie
guiais
guieis
truhan
cio
cie
ciais
cieis
crio
crie
criais
crieis
lio
lie
liais
lieis
Luis
fio
fie
fiais
fieis
trio
trie
triais
trieis
cian
pion
prion
muon
ion

Comment: I agree that most of these aren't useful. At first glance I didn't recognize a lot but realized in context I would. Some of the extra words you added, by the way, will be bisilabic for some speakers (guion can be /gjon/ or /gi'on/)

Comment: about the bi-syllabic.....please read the link...it is very interesting.....I understand your point but they should not be bi-syllabic because of the "diptongo o triptongo" however can be bi-sylabic because of the "hiato"...it is interesting as I said.

Comment: per the Ortografía de 2010, they are considered diphthongs for orthographic purposes only, without respect to the actually pronunciation which varies (pre-2010 practice was to use *guion* for monosyllabic and *guión* for bisyllabic, for instance). That is mentioned in the link you provided.